# css height property as screenSize - 300px;

Tags: css

I want to create a div that has a height equal to the screen's height, minus 300px.

How can I do this in CSS without using JavaScript?

By "screen height" I mean the height of the view port, not the display itself.

Comment: Please let me know if my edits accurately reflect the original content of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `calc` to make the element 100% the height of its container, minus 300px:

```
div {
  height: calc(100% - 300px)
}
```

If you *were* interested in the height of the viewport and not the containing element, you could use `vh`:

```
div {
   height: calc(100vh - 300px)
}
```